# How can I resize a div smoothly? Resize animations are choppy

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideup

Basically I am re-sizing a div's height using a jQuery plugin and is glitchy when using it with large images. I have tried slideUp and jquery.transit transitions, both have the same effect.

Other animations are ok, changing the margins etc.

Have a look - http://kremore.com

There are two opaque divs, top and bottom. You can see the difference. I'm changing the height for the top and changing the 'y' margin for the bottom.

The large images are the background, that fade out before the video starts.

I'm using Chrome, the problem isn't so bad in aurora but others are the same.

Comment: While I can't answer your question exactly, I made a jsFiddle that replicates the transition. It doesn't seem to result in any stuttering when I run it: http://jsfiddle.net/5fxvG/8/

Comment: No luck with that Michael, the problem is when the large images are included.